# In python, what does an array after a function call mean

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def moving_average_forecast(series, window_size):
  """Forecasts the mean of the last few values.
     If window_size=1, then this is equivalent to naive forecast"""
  forecast = []
  for time in range(len(series) - window_size):
    forecast.append(series[time:time + window_size].mean())
  return np.array(forecast)

moving_avg = moving_average_forecast(series, 30)[split_time - 30:]
```

What does this `[split_time - 30:]` mean after the function call `moving_average_forecast(series, 30)`?

PS: The `series` is an numpy array.

Thanks

Comment: It's called [array slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: It is simply a shorthand for doing: `arr = moving_average_forecast(series, 30) ; moving_avg = arr[split_time - 30:]`

Comment: Hi @venky__ I can understand the array slicing, but I didn't understand why it write like this: moving_average_forecast(series, 30)[split_time - 30:], I think it should like moving_average_forecast(series[split_time - 30:], 30).

Comment: Thanks you @Tomerikoo, now I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a shorthand for doing: arr = moving_average_forecast(series, 30) ; moving_avg = arr[split_time - 30:] Thank you @Tomerikoo